# How to write XPath for this case?

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have an XML:

```
<as>
  <a>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <data>xxx-data</data>
  </a>
  <a>
    <name>yyy</name>
    <data>yyy-data</data>
  </a>
  <a>
    <name>zzz</name>
    <data>zzz-data</data>
  </a>
</as>
```

Now I would like to write an `XPath` to select the `data` text of the element `a` with the `name` text `xxx`. This `Xpath` should return `xxx-data`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do:

```
/as/a[name="xxx"]/data
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a predicate at the `a` level to select the right `a`, then take its `data` child:

```
/as/a[name = 'xxx']/data
```